# SQL Server copy/replicate data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I have 2 servers. I need to copy some columns from 4 different tables from server 1 into the corresponding (empty) tables in server 2.

So basically, it's about replicating data from one table to another. How is this done best (and easiest)? Also, how do I make sure that the copied/replicated data is updated at the same frequency as the source (which runs completely fine and automatically)?

I want to avoid using Linked Server.

Comment: if you don't wants to use linked server then make background application to import data from one server and export to other server

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: this is my opinion let's wait for other opinion. in my case you have to create one window or console application, in which two separate connection string for both server. First execute select command from one server and collect data and then insert that data in second server with other connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this done best (and easiest)?

- For a one time replication consider a **SQL Server Import and Export Wizard**. This approach can also be scheduled by saving a final package and schedule it by SQL Agent

  Example: [Simple way to import data into SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server/)
- For a continuous, low latency data syncronization - **SQL Server Transactional Replication**.

  Further read: [Tutorial: Configure replication between two fully connected servers (transactional)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-2017)
  Worth to mention, that transactional replication is not the easiest topic, however, it fits quite good to a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The data in the destination table needs to be updated daily (as the source table), so I guess Transactional Replication is the way to go?

Comment: In that case, you can use the first option - Import/Export Wizard, it allows to save the package and set a schedule for periodic execution, some example: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s231/schedule_data_import_in_sql_server_pt2.htm. That package is to be scheduled using SQL Agent

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I've marked your answer as the solution. Thank you